# assign a time period to each value of a column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with one of the columns being a date. I need to create another column which would be a start (or end, doesn't matter) of a 2W period containing this date. Ideally this would be generalizable to any offset used by `pd.Grouper`.

Knowing `pd.Grouper` I can come up with a hacky solution using `.groupby.transform()` - but I hope there is a nicer solution.

I tried using `pd.Series.dt.to_period()` but it does not accept offsets like `"2W"` and interprets them as a weekly offset. I could not find documentation of `dt.to_period()` that would explain this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2022-01-03", "2022-01-10", "2022-01-20"], "data":[1,2,3]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
# Trying to assign a 2W period to a new column
# This is ugly and hacky, and pd.Grouper is deprecated 
# can this be made better? 
df["2W_date_grouper"] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="2W", key="date"))["data"].transform(lambda x:[x.name]*len(x))
# using .dt.to_period() seems to ignore "2W" and interpret it as "weekly" - WHY???
df["2W_date_to_period"] = df["date"].dt.to_period("2W")
```

[image: output of the code above]

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the following:

```
pd.Timedelta(days=14)

df[‘date’] = df[‘2A_date_grouper’] + pd.Timedelta(days=14)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html